# ViewStub raises error while inflating more than one layouts conditionally

Tags: android, inflate, layout-inflater, viewstub

In my app, I am having a spinner, and a **ViewStub**, depending upon the user item selection from spinner, I have to inflate different layouts and show the inflated layout below the spinner. When my app starts, **ViewStub** successfully inflates a layout on first time selection of any item from spinner. When I tries to select a new item from spinner, it raises Exception below

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewStub must have a non-null ViewGroup viewParent
```

My code so far is

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> pParent, View pView, int pPosition, long pId) {

if(pPosition == 1){
    m_cStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.text_form);
}else if(pPosition == 2){
    m_cStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.integer_form);
}
View inflated = m_cStub.inflate();
}
```

m_cStub is a **ViewStub** object created inside **onCreate()** of the Activity.

Here is my main layout xml code

```
<RelativeLayout..................>
     <spinner......................./>

     <ViewStub android:id="@+id/dynamic_form_layout"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/dynamic_form_inflated_id"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anybody please tell me where I am going wrong. If you have any other solution to solve this please share.

Thanks.

Comment: This is just guess try this `pView= m_cStub.inflate();`

Comment: @gtumca-MAC it will not work because the error is with ViewStub not with View.

Answer (score 24):

`ViewStub` is not designed to be used in scenarios like this one. After the stub is inflated, the stub is *removed* from the view hierarchy. That's why it has no parent and mentioned `IllegalStateException` raised. `ViewStub` can’t be used more than once. Also keeping long-lived reference to a `ViewStub` is unnecessary, if it is required, it's good practice to `null` it after inflating, so GC can eat it.

Consider using `addView()` / `removeView()` to replace your views. Or better use [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html).